# Azure Code First Migration Not Running Latest Migration Files

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, entity-framework-migrations

I have a up and running site with ASP.NET WebAPI2 in Azure which is code first. The project is currently under development. Whenever I change any models, I run Add-Migration and Update-Database locally and while publishing, I tick the check box "**Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)**".

But recently, I made a change and as usual ran Add-Migration and Update-Database and followed the same message while publishing. But it didn't worked. It keeps throwing error

> The model backing the context has changed since the
>   database was created.

I tried running `Update-Database -Verbose` directly into Azure DB. And surprisingly I notice that it's trying to run already migrated file and it's failing stating that same name of columns can't be added and that's why it's failing and throwing error.

But I'm unable to understand, why the newer migration file is not being executed instead why it's trying to executing the same file that has already been published.

NOTE : I must mention here that, recently I have added another MVC Project to Azure which uses same DB as it's source and I'm using DB First model there. Is it anything related to this?

Comment: Check the contents of __MigrationHistory table on your SQL Azure DB to see what it actually has a record of is applied

Comment: You could comment out the changes in the Up() and try applying them to get rid of the message then see if it recurs. Of course make sure the schema change in the Up() method made it to Azure.

Comment: Thanks a lot that fixed it. There were two files with same migration. Deleted one of them. A look at __MigrationHistory cleared everything